# SCR surge voltage rating

Tags: voltage, scr

A question on SCR/thyristor voltage rating: For SCR rated at 100A 400V.

i.e. It seems common the rated current can take 10x more surge current so 1000A surge for 100A SCR without damage.

Can also the listed 400V take much larger surge volts for a short time?
If not 10x then at least 2 or 3x?

Comment: Please take a moment to use capitalization and punctuation. Don't abbreviate as if this is just a text you are sending. Well-written questions receive answers.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please note the changes.

Comment: This is site policy. [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: No - voltage and current ratings are based on different considerations.   Current ratings usually relate to power dissipation in the decie proper and in bond leads (and more). Voltages relate more to breakdown of insulation - usually fatally. 

Providing a datasheet link for any component you are asking about helps others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

SCRs have both repetitive peak voltage ratings and non-repetitive peak voltage ratings. The non-repetitive ratings are higher, but probably not 3X; sometimes 2X and sometimes only 1.1X. If that is important for some particular application, you will need to look at spec sheets.

Semiconductor current ratings are based on maintaining the temperature of the junction at a safe level. The mass of the case and any mandatory heatsink stores thermal energy during a current surge insuring some safety margin in the event of a momentary increase in current.

There is very little in the physics of a semiconductor to preventing it from being destroyed by a momentary increase in voltage stress. The limits that are stated are hard limits. Since SCR application voltages are usually dependent on variation in the utility voltage supply, the peak voltages that they encounter are not reliably predictable. Circuit designs can protect the device to an extent with transient-suppression measures. As a result, the practice that is usually followed is to select a device with a peak repetitive voltage rating that is about twice the peak voltage that is routinely expected in the application.

There are no basic rules about peak voltages. The reason is probably pretty deep into the details of the design physics of the device. There are design variations to make SCRs more suited to forced commutation and high frequency vs. natural commutation and utility frequency. There may be some other design variations that are not so easily classified.

Comment: good info -so non destructive surge /non repetitive peak are similar?
also is there a reason this NRP voltage varies alot from one SCR to the next & is always alot less than 10x normal peak? 

ie most SCR'S seem to have atleast 10x surge current IFM or ITSM
or is there a basic rule to estimate NRP voltage without looking at datasheet. again many thx

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems common for SCRs to be able to exceed the rated current by say 10x, so 1000A surge for 100A SCR without damage.
>
> Can also the listed 400V take much larger surge volts for a short time?
> If not 10x then at least 2 or 3x?

No - voltage and current ratings are based on different considerations.
Current ratings usually relate to power dissipation in the device proper and in bond leads (and more).

Voltages relate more to breakdown of insulation - usually fatally.
You will typically be able to exceed rated voltage by only a small amount - and there is no certainty how large the amount is. I'd expect that 10% higher *probably* would not fail and that 50% higher may cause permanent damage - but this is uncertain in each case.

---

Providing a datasheet link for any component you are asking about, even when the question is a generic one,  helps others to help you.